# Should UIViews have properties?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiview, properties, uiviewcontroller

Using proper MCV with Objective-C can a UIView subclass have @propertys?

i.e. in the .h file

```
@class MyViewSubclass;

@interface MyViewSubclass : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *labelLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *valueLabel;
@end
```

or should this be done in a UIViewController subclass?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is most common to subclass UIViewController to manage the labels, fields, images, and other views within a view hierarchy. However, if you are creating a reusable component view that will be used throughout your application, then it's perfectly appropriate to subclass UIView and add properties to your subclass.

From Apple's iOS App Programming Guide:

> View controller objects manage the presentation of your app’s content on screen. A view controller manages a single view and its collection of subviews. When presented, the view controller makes its views visible by installing them in the app’s window.
>
> The UIViewController class is the base class for all view controller objects. It provides default functionality for loading views, presenting them, rotating them in response to device rotations, and several other standard system behaviors. UIKit and other frameworks define additional view controller classes to implement standard system interfaces such as the image picker, tab bar interface, and navigation interface.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 3):

It's good for views to have properties, but don't mix model logic into a view. The properties in a view should describe how the property looks, not what the property holds. I would avoid having a property named valueLabel in a view.

An example of view property names is UITableViewCell. It has properties imageView, textLabel, and detailTextLabel.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly reasonable for a `UIView` subclass to have properties.  You might need them to implement `layoutSubviews`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly reasonable, also if you want to create a reusable component that allows for interaction and better flexibility, take a look at UIControl (which is a subclass of UIView)